# Chrome extension express url

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

So At the moment, My code is listening in, and I want it to listen and then see any url which belongs under "https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/*"

How do I go about using the asterisk in my current code to make sure that all of the website can use my function ?

```
var regex = /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/gm;
var str = ["http://www.whatevershop this is/jackets/#", "https://www.whatevershop this is/shoes/#"];
var matches_array = str.match(regex);


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(tab.url);

    if (matches_array == tab.url) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "test.js"
        });
    }
});
```

The issue is when I use the asterisk (*) at the end of the slash (/) it doesn't actually let me use every single url, only the one which I enter ?

Any fixes ?

UPDATE:

Ive edited it as told, including the url and function still wont run :(

```
var regex = /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/[\w#-]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/gm;
```

And the str code is `var str = ["http://www.whateversiteyouneed.com/shop/#", "https://www.whateversiteyouneed.com/shop/#"];`

Bare in mind on the site, there are different categories, hence why the # is in place to allow it to use all of the different locations.

I'm still wondering why the script wont run though.
It's something in the script which isn't actually seeing the new url ?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want. Your regex won't match stackoverflow questions because ((\/)[\w#]+) should be ((\/)[\w#-]+) and your str array doesn't match because there's no .com

Comment: Hello Troy, Thank you for that, I have updated my original post with more information, What I really want to do is the site can have "whateveritis.com/shop/birds/#"
"whateveritis.com/shop/dogs/#"
"whateveritis.com/shop/turtle/#"

but for some reason when i do shop/# it doesn't load the function script.

Comment: I still don't quite see. You use * as a wildcard in the question, you have # in the code and then say "The issue is when I use the asterisk (*) at the end of the slash (/)" - you mean # here, right? And more importantly, you can't do array.match(regex) and even if you could, why evaluate an array and then compare it to tab.url. Are you wanting this script to only be injected for the domains in your string array? As it is, I can't see that the script is EVER executing, never mind with the # at the end. The regex matches with a # at the end no problem.

Comment: yes I want that script only to inject on the url's of "whateveritis.com/shop/#" the reason about the asterisk is because I'm still unclear whether I have to use "whateveritis.com/shop/#" or "whateveritis.com/shop/*" I want the script to inject when it sees that the url is on /shop/dogs, but also when its on shop/cats, and the categories of it can change so it could be /shop/dogs/Labrador/spotty but if i use (*) or (#) (not sure which one) then it will inject if it sees the url is past /shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want your script executed on specific urls then in your manifest add a section for content_scripts with an array of urls allowed. This is a lot simpler than using tab update events and regex and has wildcards

e.g.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.whatever.com/dogs/*"],
    "js": ["test.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
  }
]
```

Note it's an array of arrays, so you can put as many urls in 'matches' as you wish and with the outer array, you could have different scripts on different domains. Not that that's a common use case. See [extension match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

With this approach, the script is injected automatically and by default is inject once the page is idle, which is usually equivalent to after document ready. I usually use document_end if my code is to execute immediately. If the code will be invoked by a message from the background, e.g. by context menus, you can load at start.

Comment: Hello the code I want to use with the test.js is this '(function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("breed").options;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].text == "poodle") {
            x[i].selected = true;
            document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
            break;
        }
    }

    var delayMillis = 400;
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("look at")[0].click();
    }, delayMillis);


})();'

but for some reason, now it only adds that dog once i refresh the page, and not when I originally

Comment: Click on it, Im not sure why it would only do on refresh ?

Comment: It's a new question now. If my answer helped please upvote it or accept it and maybe ask a new question but this time post the content of manifest.json and the other files and the site you're trying it on.

Comment: Ive asked with no reply now :(